# How can I use PHP to get specific DOM nodes?

Tags: php, dom

I can get all `<a>` tags using PHP's DOMDocument, but how can I get just the ones inside of the `<ul>` list? I tried `$items->childNodes` with no luck. Should I just switch to the [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)?

```
$string = '
<html>
<head>
</head>
    <body>

        <p>Please visit my site:
            <a href="http://mysite.com/">My Site</a>
        </p>

        <p>My friend's sites:</p>
        <ul>
            <a href="http://friend1.com/">Friend 1</a>
            <a href="http://friend2.com/">Friend 2</a>
            <a href="http://friend3.com/">Friend 3</a>
        </ul>

    </body>
</html>
';


$DOM = new DOMDocument;
@$DOM->loadHTML($string);

$items = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('a');

for ($i = 0; $i < $items->length; $i++){
    echo $items->item($i)->nodeValue;
    echo '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php).

$xpath->query("//ul/a");

I've built pretty complex selectors using xpath.  It's really powerful.